# Jasper Reports Custom global or built in parameter

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

In my application I have a setting that can be configured by the user called Date Format.  There are a list of formats they can use and when they choose one, all dates in the application and in the reports use that format.

Every time I create a new report I have to create the parameter and link the input control.  I just added a new setting, for formatting numbers.  I have about 50 reports that I need to apply this to.  After going through the monotonous task of adding the parameter and input control to every report I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Is it possible to create a custom global parameter that is automatically available to all reports (Similar to the built in parameters)?

Furthermore, is there a way to tell jasper if a field is of a certain type to automatically do something with it, on a global level.  For example if my field type is 'decimal' apply the number format?

Answer (score 0):

Every report has a `REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY` parameter that is an instance of [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.FormatFactory](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/FormatFactory.html). You should be able to create your class that implements `FormatFactory` and in the constructor takes what ever you need to determine the correct format. Then add it to the parameters when exporting your report.

You will probably need to play with it, as I am not sure what it passes in for `pattern` when a value is/isn't set. And if you always ignore the pattern, then when you need to explicitly set it to be the same in all reports it will cause problems.

If I get time tonight, I will try to create an example and see how it works and update my answer, or if you beat me to it, you could post a comment letting us know how it works.